# What could cause a gameobject to disappear in the game window, but not in the scene window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that moves my `GameObject` to another `GameObject`. When the object is launched (instantiated), after about 1 second it goes invisible in the game window, but I can still see it in the scene window and it still collides with the target `GameObject` like it's supposed to.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

This is the script attached to the gameobject to make it move to the closest enemy:

```
GameObject FindClosestEnemy() {
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("target");
    GameObject closest = null;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}



// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    targetz = FindClosestEnemy ();

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetz.transform.position, 1f);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide bit more details, if possible with code sample - so that we can help you.

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure what code could be causing  this though, as the object behaves like it should (moves to the closest tagged object and gets destroyed on collision). However, it just seems to turn invisible in the game window, even though I can still see it in the scene window.